# Change markercluster depending quantity

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was reading this thread: [Google Maps Api v3, custom Cluster icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416089/google-maps-api-v3-custom-cluster-icon)

The thread, explain how we can change the icons of our makrerclusters but, is possible add as variable the quantity? I mean, if the group is of 2 markers display x image, if the group is of 6  markers display other image, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision which icon to use will be made by the `calculator`-function of the MarkerClusterer.

You may use a custom calculator-function (may be added via the setCalculator-method.)

The default-calculator:

```
function(markers, numStyles) {
  var index = 0;
  var count = markers.length;
  var dv = count;
  while (dv !== 0) {
    dv = parseInt(dv / 10, 10);
    index++;
  }

  index = Math.min(index, numStyles);
  return {
    text: count,
    index: index
  };
};
```

As you see, there will be passed 2 arguments:

1. `markers`: the markers for the cluster
2. `numStyles`: the number of styles available for the MarkerClusterer-instance(by default 5).

The calculator must return an object with the properties:

- text(text to display, usually the number of markers in the cluster)
- index(the index of the style that has to be applied)

So what you have to do is:

1. setup your custom styles(icons)
2. apply your custom calculator-function that returns the desired index