# Google map marker cluster... grouping customize by a value in markers

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to create a cluster with a specific value stored in the marker.
Is this possible?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ag0T6.jpg)

Comment: Potentially.  Please provide some more details about what you mean by that (a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue would be helpful).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Maps Api v3, custom Cluster icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416089/google-maps-api-v3-custom-cluster-icon)

Answer (score -1):

You can override the image path of the marker cluster like this

```
let markers = [marker1, marker2, marker3]; // list of markers with the specific value

markerClusterOptions = {
    styles: [
        {
            height: 53,
            width: 53,
            url: YOUR_ICON_PATH
        }
    ]
};

let markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, markerClusterOptions);
```

**NB**: `styles` is a list and you can have more than one style depending for exemple the `height` and `width`.